# can't add foreign key constraint in table assigned

Tags: mysql

```
create table assigned(
        num int,
        tripdate date,
        PRIMARY KEY(num),
        FOREIGN KEY(num) REFERENCES seats(num),
        FOREIGN KEY(tripdate) REFERENCES trip(tripdate)
);

create table trip(
        num int,
        tripdate date,
        meal varchar(50),
        PRIMARY KEY(num,tripdate),
        FOREIGN KEY(num) REFERENCES ticket(num)
);

create table seats(
        aircraft_seats_id varchar(50),
        num int,
        class varchar(50),
        PRIMARY KEY(aircraft_seats_id,num), 
        FOREIGN KEY(aircraft_seats_id) REFERENCES aircraft(crafts_id)
);
```

create table seats(
        aircraft_seats_id varchar(50),
        num int,
        class varchar(50),
        PRIMARY KEY(aircraft_seats_id,num), 
        FOREIGN KEY(aircraft_seats_id) REFERENCES aircraft(crafts_id)
);

Error is in table assigned can't add foreign key constraint

Comment: The target table of a fk must exists when you want to create the fk.

Comment: What is the actual purpose of table `assigned`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your statement. You can’t assign same name as primary key and also as foreign key.  Note: foreign key is simply to reference a primary from another table.

Comment: Can you please provide more specific details I am not getting it.  Big Thanks